# Имя подключения инета на C#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, хочу выдернуть только имя подключения интернета, делаю так:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in interfaces)
{                
    Console.WriteLine (adapter.Name);
}
```

А получаю целых 3 строки, на второй лежит реальное имя подключение, мне нужно только оно. Вот какие данные приходят:

```
Подключение по локальной сети 12
Интертелеком
MS TCP Loopback interface
```

Достать нужно только имя, т.е. **Интертелеком** , помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство **OperationalStatus**.

> Указывает операционное состояние сетевого интерфейса.
>
> **Up** Сетевой интерфейс работает и может передавать пакеты данных.

Answer (score 1):

А я бы обратил внимание на свойство [**`NetworkInterfaceType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype.aspx). Из всего набора сетевых интерфейсов следует, как минимум, исключить петли (**`NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback`**).
Но лучше всего, посмотрите значения этого свойства у всех интерфейсов и выберите нужные.

Comment: Увы, не исключено, что платформенно-независимого решения не найти. Но вот платформенно-зависимое... Найти через какой интерфейс идёт дефолтный маршрут (или анализирую вывод команды `route print`, или средствами winapi) и его и выдавать. Поскольку речь идёт о "подключению к интернету", то должно работать.